# Align some nav-pills elements to right in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, nav, twitter-bootstrap-4, nav-pills

I am using Bootstrap 4-beta2's `nav-pills` to implement tabbed interface.

How do I align some elements to the right of the screen?

Setting `ml-auto` on the last `li` item does not work. Splitting up the `ul` in two `ul`'s does not work either because it allows `tabright` to be active at the same time as, say, `tableft1`.

```
<nav class="fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#tabmain">Brand</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-pill active"><a class="nav-link" href="#tableft1" data-toggle="pill">TabLeft1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#tableft2" data-toggle="pill">TabLeft2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#tabright" data-toggle="pill">TabRight</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `navbar` is flex, so flex-specific classes are helping:

```
<nav class="fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="navbar justify-content-start flex-nowrap">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#tabmain">Brand</a>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills w-100">
            <li class="nav-pill active"><a class="nav-link" href="#tableft1" data-toggle="pill">TabLeft1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-pill"><a class="nav-link" href="#tableft2" data-toggle="pill">TabLeft2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-pill ml-auto"><a class="nav-link" href="#tabright" data-toggle="pill">TabRight</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```